# Fail trumpet onomatopoeia

Tags: onomatopoeia

There are several sound clips that are widely understood to mean "(epic) fail". I think the most famous one is the one with the oboe or trumpet... 4 notes with declining pitch, the last one being stretched out.

- Is there a common way to capture that in writing?

Comment: One note is worth 76 words.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most common ways I've seen are writing out the words:

> sad trombone
>   :( trombone

Or to use the onomatopoeic

> Wah, Wah, Wah, Wahhhhhhh …
>   Womp, Womp, Womp, Wommmmmp… (at the behest of several commenters)

Or to combine them:

> sad trombone: wah, wah, wah, wahhhhh …

Comment: Perfect... I was trying all kinds of "wua, ua, wue" on Youtube and I couldn't find anything :)

Comment: Yes, onomatopoeia varies from language to language. It makes it challenging to look it up …

Comment: +1 I would have used similar onomatopoeia, but had never heard of "sad trombone".

Comment: @TecBrat I initially couldn't remember it either. I googled sad trumpet which didn't sound right to me. And sad trombone came right up.  It was an aha moment …

Comment: I also saw "womp, womp, womp" and I like "wom, wom, wowowom".

Comment: @TecBrat excellent onomatopoeic terms as well.

Comment: @David M: Sometimes it is a trumpet, with the mute on. A popular musical trope in the Ealing comedies of the '50s.

Comment: @Terpsichore I don't doubt that.  But, the trope seems to be sad trombone.

Comment: The spelling "womp womp womp" even has a single-purpose website associated with it: http://wompwompwomp.com/

Comment: But that sound isn't wompwompwomp.  It's wompwompwompwomp.  The name "womp womp" to me conjures up a different sound [not sure where to most easily find it] which smears the first three notes together [it's a trombone after all].

Comment: Same here. "Womp womp" does not invoke the sad trombone sound to me.

Answer (score 12):

This is known as the "sad trombone" (see as a reference: http://www.sadtrombone.com/)

Comment: Sound like a duck for me...